# Responsive map with mark (div element)

Tags: html, css

everybody
I have problem with responsive map (this is only image not real map). I try to stick div element on this map for example: my mark(div) is on Paris but when I resize window mark is in other country :D I want stick this element for this one country. I try like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid map">
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.map {
    background-image: url(../images/only-map.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.circle {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    right: 400px;
    float: right;
}
```

I try with position absolute, fixed. Background size cover,contain, 100% 100%, but still not working.

Thank  for every advance

Comment: Can you please create a working snippet / fiddle etc?

Comment: Provide a real working example (jsfiddle/snippet) that shows exactly the problem. By looking only at code it's not easy to understand the problem/what you see.

Comment: Of course please here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/mumxyrp5/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="map rel">
   <div class="dot abs">
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.map{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.dot{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

.rel{
  position: relative;
}

.abs{
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 8px;
}
```

You can play around with it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vuyp4364/2/). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a position in percentage

```
.circle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

but keep in mind that your circle will be centered on it's corner, wich you can prevent by adjusting your percentages and setting:

```
.circle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); //else only the upper-left corner of the circle div will be centered on paris)
}
```

as it has been said, it's always hard to help without seeing the actual image and result, but this might work

Comment: Hi, I have one more problem. I must center map (this same on small and extra large screen) . So I try with background-size: cover but the problem is mark on this map. Can I stick this point?  Because when I resize window picture is smaller and points is wrong country. Percentage work only for background-size: 100% 100%. Can I do it diffrent way than media query?
Thanks for your help

Comment: percentage works with any size of background, you just have a little math to do if you want to resize using background (maybe padding can be an option ?) if you show me a jsfiddle with your problem i can show you :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yn0wm2kp/ check this :) 
Now I use background-size: cover because this show the problem. When I resize window images is bigger or smaller but point is always one place. I want to customize point to image :)

Comment: yeah, thats normal, why would you want to use background-size:cover, as it  can hide half of the map if your resolution is not the exact precise one ? if your city is out of the visible part of the map, what do you want to do with your circle ?

Comment: Yes I understand :) but can I add background-size (other than cover) which is a solution? Because map must be center and not full width (for large screen looking ugly)

Comment: maybe using contain ? background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: contain;background-position: center;

Comment: Ok I try use contain :) I think this is easy task but definitely not :D Thank you for advices :)